# Consequences of cocompactness for discrete subgroups of hyperbolic isometries

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups, geometric-topology, hyperbolic-geometry

I'm just get off the ground understanding some hyperbolic geometry / group theory and I came here to seek some help on some basic questions.  In particular, I am reading through the hyperbolic estimates in the first sections of Cannon's "The Combinatorial Structure of Cocompact Discrete Hyperbolic Groups".  Once the geometry comes into the picture, I seem to be doing alright, but I am having trouble understanding a couple compactness/point-set-topological arguments that come in at the beginning Cannon's article that I did not understand and I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

Here is the setting: $G$ is a finitely-generated subgroup of the isometry group of $\mathbb{H}^n$ for some $n$ with $\mathbb{H}^n/G$ compact and such that the action of $G$ on $\mathbb{H}^n$ is discrete (i.e., for every compact set $K \subset \mathbb{H}^n$, there are only finitely many $G$-translates of $K$ that intersect $K$).  In addition, $C$ is a finite generating set for $G$ and $\Gamma$ is the Cayley graph of $G$ with respect to this generating set.  Further, $\ast \in \mathbb{H}^n$ is a point on which $G$ acts freely.

(1) Why does such a point $\ast$ necessarily exist?

Using the action of $G$ on $\ast$ we then obtain a $G$-equivariant map $\phi : \Gamma \to \mathbb{H}^n$ that sends the edges to where they send $\ast$ and sends edges to hyperbolic geodesics.  The following statements appear in the proof of Theorem 1.1 in the above paper and I do not understand / would like to understand the proofs:

(2) There exists a number $\alpha$ such that each point in $\mathbb{H}^n$ is within $\alpha$ of an element in $\phi(\Gamma)$.

(3) There exists a compact set $K \subset \mathbb{H}^n$ such that any two points in $\mathbb{H}^n$ of distance less than $2\alpha + 1$ lie in some $G$-translate of $K$.

Does anyone know how the proofs of these statements go?  I do not at all know how to use the hypothesis that $\mathbb{H}^n/G$ is compact.

Comment: 1 and 2 are true, but 3 is false (as written). Hint for 1: Prove that $G$ is countable and that the fixed-point set of every nontrivial element of $G$ is nowhere dense in $H^n$.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thanks for the comment - that makes sense for (1) (since the group is finitely generated, it is countable, and isometry can't fix an open ball without being the identity,  and then by the Baire category theorem since $\mathbb{H}^n$ is complete it cannot be written as the countable union of nowhere dense sets).  Do you have any hints for (2)? Why is (3) false?

Comment: I misread (3): it is true as well.